# Smart Folders on Windows XP & Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, smart

Is there a way to create a "Smart folder" on Vista & XP? (similar to the functionality available on Mac)

Looks like there are some predefined "Search folders" on Vista. Is there a way to specify my own search criterion and create a custom 'Search folder'?

Answer (score 1):

[Smart Folders in Windows Vista](http://theabc.typepad.com/my_weblog/2009/01/smart-folders-in-windows-vista.html)

Answer (score 0):

While not *exactly* smart folders like Mac OS X means it, you can save searches easily in Windows XP & Vista.

Search for a string, and then go to File > Save search (I'm using Windows XP). It will then save the search wherever you want and you can use that at a later time.